# no command prompt in jupyter qtconsole

Tags: python, jupyter, qtconsole

After starting **jupyter qtconsole** I get only an empty window with the usual menu on top but no command prompt. When I hit enter I get three dots (like multilinecommand) but again no prompt -> nothing happens if I type any text. 
A few weeks ago the jupyter qtconsole was working perfectly fine.

My System:

```
Windows 10 Pro
jupyter 4.1.0
qtconsole 4.2.1
```

I un- and reinstalled both with pip and Canopy. No success. I can restart the kernel with "control-." but still no prompt.
Any ideas how to get the qtconsole running in Windows?